# storing an app icon in a drawable folder

Tags: android

Is there a way to draw store an application icon in a drawable folder? 
I would like to display the application icon next to the application name in a list view.

I know there is a method to get the icon but I am not too sure how to store that icon so I can use it at a later time.

Answer (score 2):

The application icon should already be stored in a drawable folder (in fact best practice is to have one stored in every density drawable folder)

You should be able to reference it at runtime just like anyother drawable using `R.drawable.ic_launcher` or whatever name you gave the file if it wasn't `ic_launcher`

so to put it into an ImageView you could do something like

```
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Comment: I did not name it anything. is ic_launcher it's default name after upon storing?

Comment: Yes, if you create a blank project with eclipse it will give you ic_launcher.png inside each of your drawable folders. By default it is a little green android robot.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your answer. I have a list of applicationInfo. I am iterating through it so i can call the method getApplicationIcon().

are you saying i can just do
Iterator<ApplicationInfo> getIcons = applications.iterator();
        Drawable icon; 
        ImageView myImage = new ImageView(this);
        while( getIcons.hasNext() ) {
         icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon( getIcons.next() );
         myImage.setImageDrawable( icon );
        
        } ??